# Linked lists as matrix and efficiency

Tags: java, sparse-matrix

When a big matrix needs to be used in an algorithm, to speed up complexity we were told to use linked lists if the matrix is sparse. Meaning that if the data is mostly the same we can save only the data that are not that value.

But how do we identify the point where using a sparse matrix is not useful anymore ?

For a square matrix of length *n* how do we calculate the point where we can say that the matrix has too much non-zero data to be written in a linked list ?

I imagine we need to use the memory sizes of an object, a link between two objects, then use our density factor. But what are the calculations to safely say *"This matrix has x% non-zero data, it is better to use a linked list* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on what you optimize for. Do you optimize for space or time?

Let's say you optimize for space. To keep data of a square matrix of length n, you need n*n numbers (to simplify, let's say it's an integer for each value). In case of a linked list, you need to have the actual value, the coordination of the value in the matrix and the pointer to the next non-zero value. To simplify, let's say each of those fields is of an integer size. So for a linked list, you need 4 integers for a single value to keep (plus additional data like the head of the linked list).

IMHO, once less than 1/4 of the values in the matrix is non-zero, it's more optimal to use a linked list than an array of arrays.

Obviously, there are other options to keep the matrix values; then the ratio can be different.

To optimize for time, again, it depends which operations you want to run...